# LIstener for D-pad center press android

Tags: android-studio, android-source

I am developing a device that interacts with android-auto.
the launcher application installed on the device has custom widgets that have onClickLIstener implemented. 
therefore if I press ENTER on my keyboard the onclick is activated and I can navigate the user successfully. however, when the user presses the D-PAD which has a scan code of 23 the input is successfully injected into the android but the onclick listener isn't activated. 
I would like to know how can I implement a view, a button for example, that has a listener for the d-pad scan code.